# Correct syntax for javascript redirect with parameters

Tags: javascript, redirect

I need to modify the below code that, run from Submit in a Caspio form as a popup, to redirect the parent page (instead of refreshing it) and close the popup.

The current code is:

```html
<script>
    setTimeout(function() {
            window.parent.location.reload();
            window.parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();},
        2000);
</script>
```

I think something like the below is what I need but I can't get the syntax right:

```html
setTimeout(function() {
        window.parent.location.href='../my-webpage?PID=[@field:PID]&PTID=[@field:PTID]'();
        window.parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();},
    2000);
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Setting the location, you will not be able to change anything on the parent right after it........

Comment: `[@field:PID]` is what syntax? Where are you getting the values from?

Comment: Why you have () after the url? I tested without it and the code worked just fine.

Comment: Those field:PID and PTID parts are from Caspio datapage fields. They're field values that are numbers in this case. It might be clearer in this thread to just use a hard number in place of field:PID and PTID (I should of thought of that when I posted).

Comment: That's exactly it- just remove the () after the url. I hadn't tried that particular approach. Works perfectly- many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
window.parent.location.href=window.location.hostname; window.parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();
}, 2000);
```

Its will redirect to current domain

Then for parent by "/"

```
var currentURL = window.parent.location.href;
var lastDir = currentURL.substr(currentURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
var parentURL = currentURL.replace(lastDir,"");

   setTimeout(function(){ 
    window.parent.location.href=parentURL; window.parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();
    }, 2000);
```

Its will redirect to parent of domain by "/" as separator.

example my current https://stackoverflow.com/posts/parent/child

so will redirent to

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/parent